# Is Epsilon ε an independant number (in limits)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

---

does ε always have to be a number

if i know a certain limit exists can i choose episolon (for a certain alpha ) and knowing our function f(x)=/=0
and

f:lR -> lR

to be 
ε=|f(x)|

|x-a| $<$ α ⇒ |f(x)-l|<|f(x)|

for a certain alpha

### i really hope my question is clear

here's another example where this would be useful if it was right:(proving product rule of limits)

|g(x)-m|$<$B and |f(x)-n|$<$B
n is the limit of f and m is the limit of g 
by choosing alpha we obtain

|f(x)g(x)-nm| $<$  |f(x)| |g(x)-m|+ |m(f(x)-n)|

i choose A= $\frac{N}{2|m|}$
we obtain  |f(x)g(x)-nm| $<$  |f(x)| |g(x)-m|+ $\frac{N}{2}$

can we choose B=$\frac{N}{2|f(x)|}$?

Comment: Compare: lR and $\mathbb{R}$, ==> and $\Rightarrow$, alpha and $\alpha$ etc.

Comment: $fg=\frac{1}{4}[(f+g)^2-(f-g)^2]$

Comment: If you really want your question to be clear, as you claim, then there are several things you could do. (1) Learn a little LaTeX. I dislike it myself, but learning a little is the price of entry around here. (2) Fix the spelling, grammar, and punctuation. You're not writing a text message to your buddies. Grammar matters, to many people here. It certainly matters to me. (3) Make sure you explain all the symbols you use. You can't assume that everyone uses the same symbols in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Given the quality of your question, I can't really tell what you're asking. But here's a wild guess.

Look again at the definition of "limit". When we say that 
$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = k
$$
we mean the following, according to the definition:

No matter what number $\epsilon >0$ I give you, you can then find a number $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - k| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x-a| < \delta$.

So, **first** I choose an $\epsilon$, and **then** you have to find some $\delta$ that works. The $\delta$ you find can depend on what $\epsilon$ I give you, and it can also depend on $a$. Certainly you are not required to find a single fixed $\delta$ that will work for every $\epsilon$.

So, for example, suppose $f(x) = x^2$, $a=0$, and $k=0$. If I give you $\epsilon = 0.01$, then you could choose $\delta = 0.1$. In general, if I give you any value $\epsilon$, you can choose $\delta = \sqrt\epsilon$, and that will work.